# How to get the contents of the response of an HttpClient call

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

```
  public WorkItem CreateWorkItem(string title, string description, string comments)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57765/API.svc/CreateWorkItem?title="+title+"&description="+description+"&history="+comments, null).Result.Content;
        //var task = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57765/API.svc/CreateWorkItem?title=" + title + "&description=" + description + "&history=" + comments, null);
        var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57765/API.svc/CreateWorkItem?title=" +title+"&description="+description+"&history="+ comments, null).Result;
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var workItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkItem>(result);
        return workItem;
    }
```

[image]
Issue is: reading the response of my call to the API,

I also get an error when using "Content" Task does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type "Content" Task could be found

Goal is to use ajax to hit this method to fire off the api call and populate my WorkItem with data and to read that response after the call is completed.

```
 public class WorkItem
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What kind of application is this? It is not a good idea to block on async code with `.Result`.

Comment: This is a MVC app

Comment: You will be back asking another question when your code deadlocks. Make all of your code async or use HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make much sense to make an async call, then follow up by waiting for the async call to complete. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I'll quickly walk you through the flow. Ajax call from the view hits this method that then populates the link with the contents from the view. Then after I hit this method in my model I hit my own API to fire a call off to Microsoft API. So what I need is to populate this link in my method to hit my api to go to microsoft. I need to read the response also

Answer (score 1):

You see that it's "Post**Async**" meaning that it return `Task<HttpWebResponse>` so you have to `await` it or block it until you get result (`.Result`)

```
var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57765/API.svc/CreateWorkItem?title="+title+"&description="+description+"&history="+comments, null).Result;
```

or

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57765/API.svc/CreateWorkItem?title="+title+"&description="+description+"&history="+comments, null);
```

Then using NewstonSoft.Json

```
var workItem = JsonConvert.Deserialize<WorkItem>(contents);
```

Comment: So that Fixed my issue but why? It also didn't fix it completly because when I return contents I get a "cannot implicitly convert type string to Models.WorkItem.

Comment: Added some comment above

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! Learning something new all the time! Thank you. So my method requires me to return my WorkItem but It doesn't look like the response from the call will fill my model properly. How would I be able to return WorkItem properly?

Comment: Just deserialize it

Comment: Should I be using ReadAsStringAsync()? var contents = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: "await" it or ".Result" is up to you to decide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161123/discussion-between-dominic-gozza-and-rawitas-krungkaew).

Comment: This doesn't address the fundamental issue, which is WHY async if you're doing it in serial?

Comment: I agree with you. However, there is no method without async in HttpClient class, and it is up to the design.Although, there are benefits of refraining from blocking IO.

Comment: There is no law saying you must use `HttpClient`. There are always API choices.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.PostAsync()
```

is an asynchronous method and it will return only the task not the result. If you want to get the result back then you need to await the response from the API. 
using

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57765/API.svc/CreateWorkItem?title="+title+"&description="+description+"&history="+comments, null)
var workItem = JsonConvert.Deserialize<WorkItem>(response.Content);
```

This is how we can access the data. But to achieve this your method should be mark as 'async', then only you can make use the 'await' keyword. Another method is,

```
var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57765/API.svc/CreateWorkItem").Result.Content
var workItem = JsonConvert.Deserialize<WorkItem>(response);
```

But this is not a good practice to use result on the awaitable method. Because we cant make use of the asynchronicity of that feature.

Otherwise,

```
var task = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57765/API.svc/CreateWorkItem");
task.wait();
var workItem = JsonConvert.Deserialize<WorkItem>(task.Result.Content);
```

This also not a good approach. These are all the options you have if you are not using 'async' function.

```
public WorkItem CreateWorkItem(string title, string description, string comments)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var task = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57765/API.svc/CreateWorkItem?title="+title+"&description="+description+"&history="+comments, null);
task.Wait();
        var contents = task.Result.Content;
    }
```

Comment: What other options would I have if I am not using the async function I would like to explore those options because doing what I am doing currently has not worked and even with everyones help I can't fix it.

Comment: If you cant use 'async' keyword means, follow the last approach. It will be better compared to the 2nd one. Wait the task until finish and use the 'Result' property of the returned task to access the content.

Comment: Well using the wait keyboard is what gives me the issue. saying httpresponsemessage does not contain a definition for wait

Comment: If you are using
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost");
the response variable should be of type HttpResponeMessage.
If you are using without await.
var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost");
The response variable is of type Task<HttpResponseMessage>. You can use 'wait()' method only on type Task<HttpResponseMessage>

If your variable is of type 'HttpResponseMessage', the directly use the Content property

Comment: Hmm still gives me the issue with the .wait

Comment: I have give a sample in my answer above, can you try the last section in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161129/discussion-between-dominic-gozza-and-sharmapattar).